# NSDate 24h format: delete first '0' from hours

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

When I want a date in 24 hour format, I see the hours such as 05:00. How can I delete the first 0 to get 5:00? I tried this:

```
NSDateFormatter *fhours = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fhours setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
mystring = [fhours stringFromDate:newDate];
[fhours release];
```

Comment: Make sure you check Blade's answer as he got there first :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSString *theTime = [timeFormat stringFromDate:now];
```

At line

```
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```

You can erase one H like this

```
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the right result with the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *fhours = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fhours setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];
mystring = [fhours stringFromDate:newDate];
[fhours release];
```